# No sound output through HDMI-cabled TV in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, hdmi

I've read similar questions on this website but, to no avail.

I have had zero luck solving this problem even with a FOSS article on it.

Basically, when I plug in an HDMI cable, I get no sound output on my tv. I have tried more than one cable and I have mucked around with the sound settings forever.

When I enter this command in the terminal: open PulseAudio Volume Control

I get this result: `Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console`

When I also enter in the command: `lspci | grep Audio`

I get this result:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
```